# How to provide Django label_tag and as_widget arguments (e.g. contents and attrs)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

From django/forms/forms.py:

```
def label_tag(self, contents=None, attrs=None):
    ..

def as_widget(self, widget=None, attrs=None, only_initial=False):
    ..
```

From my templates I call the label_tag as follows:

```
{{ form.my_field.label_tag }}
```

which outputs the label.

How should I provide the arguments to those tag as in their definition?
For example I want to provide an alternative label text and css classes.

I tried something like:

```
{{ form.my_field.label_tag contents='My alternative label' }}
```

but it gives me:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' contents='My alternative label'' from 'form.code.label_tag contents='My alternative label''
```

The same goes for the attrs field. Can I supply a value for that one from the template. I would like to provide the css class.
For css class I'm using a filter at the moment but while going through the Django source code I noticed label_tag and as_widget has these additional arguments, and that's why I'm wondering now I can supply them from my templates.

(I'm using Django 1.4 on App Engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django very deliberately limits template functionality to ensure you don't end up writing the whole website in the template as you might with PHP.

From the [The Django Book 2.0: Templates: Philosophies and Limitations](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html#philosophies-and-limitations):

> ...it’s impossible to call Python code directly within Django
>   templates. All “programming” is fundamentally limited to the scope of
>   what template tags can do.

You *could* [write a custom template tag or filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that does what you want...*but* — as this seems to be form logic — you would almost certainly be better off doing something else.

Simplest might be to define the label/widget where the form is defined. ie:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.CharField(label='My label', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

That said, for the widget, there are [other documented ways](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets). If you use [django-floppy-forms](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/) you can easily override the whole template used to render them.

Finally, I highly recommend [django-crispyforms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/). It saves you a lot of time because you no longer have the pain of hand-writing forms in templates.

Comment: Thanks Meshy, I'm currenly using custom render_field and render_label tags for this. Imo this doesn't look like form logic, it's just about appearance and styling. Providing css classes inside the form itself doesn't feel right, and it also makes it hard to design the page. But the reason I'm asking is that as I mentioned the Django label and as_widget functions on the have the ability to provide contents (labels) and attrs. I'm now calling these methods form my custom tags.

Comment: Adding styling info to the form does seem a little backwards, and breaks decoupling a little bit. That said, now I'm used to doing it the crispy-forms way, I wouldn't go back. It's a different flow for front-end, but it's saved me hours of pain.